# Installer for Microsoft Office Add In

Tags: c#, ms-office, clickonce, nsis, office365

I am working on a Microsoft Office Add In.

The current installer uses NSIS, but does not provide automatic updates.

I would like to provide either optional or mandatory updates in the most user friendly manner possible. It must work for all versions of Office.

What is the standard/ best way of doing this please?

My research so far has not provided a stand-out option. Best articles I've found listed below:

- Article from [Scott Hanselmann](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAutomaticallyNotifyTheUserThatItsTimeToUpgradeAWindowsApp.aspx)
- [VSTO](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/VSTO-Deploy-an-Office-fbcc09ad)
- [Click Once](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx), though some people seem against it, I'm not sure why?
- NSIS auto updating [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228353/nsis-automatic-and-silent-update) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361450/nsis-silent-autoupdate-application) - not sure if we can get the optional/mandatory option here easily.
- [Chocolatey](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/CreatePackages) - would prefer to keep everything under my control, so not really an option.

Any pointers much appreciated.

UPDATE - Following the answer, some more references for anyone searching.

- Some [downsides](https://choksheak.wordpress.com/tag/clickonce-installation-downsides-disadvantages/) with clickonce - most of which shouldn't be a problem for me.
- Deploying [clickonce on amazon](http://geekswithblogs.net/saifkhan/archive/2009/09/03/clickonce-hosting-with-amazon-s3.aspx).
- [Difference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) between clickonce and standard installer.
- Clickonce signing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610556/how-to-sign-a-clickonce-application) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/che5h906.aspx).

UPDATE 2: Further to this - Although I like ClickOnce on WPF applications, updates were troublesome when used for an Office Add in. We ended up creating our own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ClickOnce if you want to implement the auto-update feature. All other ways require to uninstall the add-in first and only then you can install a new version of the software.

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx) article describes the required steps in depth for creating ClickOnce installers.